# javascript get comma separted or single value from text field

Tags: javascript, regex

What I am trying to get here is, i have a text field with no  max length.

It can have single text or comma separated text. I want to get a regex, or way to cater for single or comma separted values and remove commma, if it's after last text and finally put the results in javascript array.

Example:

- Scenario #1: Textfield: abcdef
- Scenario #2: Textfield:   abcd1, werwe23 ,hfghf,2345,sedwe
- Scenario #3: Textfield: abcd1, werwe23, hfghf,2345,sedwe, (by   mistake of user).

Here's my sample code so far which caters for the ones with comma.

A suggestion with regex will help my cause.

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <title> Get values </title>
            <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
            <meta name="Author" content="">
            <meta name="Keywords" content="">
            <meta name="Description" content="">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function getValues()
            {
            var val = document.getElementById("txtInput").value;
            var splitted = val.split(',');
            alert("splitted: "splitted);
            }
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
            <input type="text" id="txtInput"/>
            <input type="button" onclick="javascript:getvalues();" value="get values"/>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to remove any trailing commas or whitespace before splitting:

```
val = val.replace(/[,\s]+$/, '');
```

In your code:

```
> alert("splitted: "splitted);
```

should be:

```
 alert("splitted: " + splitted);
```

and

```
>   <input ... onclick="javascript:getvalues();" ... />
```

should be:

```
  <input ... onclick="getvalues();" ... >
```

the `javascript:` part is read as a usless label.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob for your suggestion and time, appreciate it. I tried it out and it seems to be working, if i have any issues, i will come back here or ask a new question.